# Firebase remote config - creating parameter groups programmatically

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, firebase-remote-config

I have created a cloud function to update my remote configs in a specific manner. I followed   the guide as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc#modify_remote_config_parameters).

Following is the code snippet.

```
exports.updateTenantFeatures = functions
  .region(DEFAULT_LOCATION)
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
     if (!context.auth) {
       throw new UnauthenticatedError(
        constants.ERROR_TEXT.CIVIS_UNAUTHENTICATED_TEXT,
        constants.ERROR_CODE.CIVIS_UNAUTHENTICATED, 
     );
    }

    const country = getCountryName(data.countryCode);
    const poolId = data.poolId;
    const remoteConfig = admin.remoteConfig();
    const template = await remoteConfig.getTemplate();

    const featureList = JSON.stringify({ [data.featureName]: data.featureState });

    template.parameterGroups[`${country}_${poolId}`].parameters[`${country}_${poolId}_features`] = {
      valueType: "JSON",
      defaultValue: {
      value: featureList,
    },
    description: `tenant of pool id ${poolId} from ${country}'s feature list`
    }

    const result = await remoteConfig.publishTemplate(template);

    return {
      result: constants.RESULT.SUCCESS, 
      tenantFeatuerList: result.parameters[`${country}_${poolId}_features`] 
    };
  
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error?.type === constants.ERROR_TYPE.UNAUTHENTICATED ||
         error?.type ===  constants.ERROR_TYPE.UNAUTHORIZED)
      { 
        return { result: constants.RESULT.ERROR, code: error.code, details: error.message }
      }
      return { result: constants.RESULT.ERROR }
      }
   });
```

The goal of this function is to create parameters nested inside a parameter group programmatically. Attached image depicts how this is expected to be structured.

[image: remote config required structure]

Problem is when I'm using `` template.parameterGroups[`${country}_${poolId}`]... `` it doesn't create a parameter group as expected. It throws the following error in Logs.

> error in updateTenantFeatures : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parameters')

But however if I ignore creating the parameter group and focus on creating parameters by removing the `parameterGroups` as `` template.parameters[`${country}_${poolId}_features`] = ... `` it creates just the parameter.

Is the parameter group creation restricted by the admin sdk ? Or is the SDK having some issue(s) in creating parameter groups ?

Comment: The error message is telling you that `template.parameterGroups[\`${country}_${poolId}\`]` is undefined. What are you expecting it to be instead?  You have a lot of variables here that we can't see, so we don't know much about what you're actually working with. Try logging everything to see that it's all what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm trying to create the parameter group along with the parameter nested inside it. I debugged this a couple of times & the issue I'm facing is that the SDK won't allow it. It seems that the SDK only allows to nest the parameter inside parameter groups that are available.

Comment: Based on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#create_groups_programmatically) it seems I can achieve my goal with the REST api. I'm attempting to do the same thing here with the node admin SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out to do this by making a simple if condition in the code.

```js
exports.updateTenantFeatures = functions
  .region(DEFAULT_LOCATION)
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
      ...

      const country = getCountryName(data.countryCode);
      const poolId = data.poolId;
      const remoteConfig = admin.remoteConfig();
      const template = await remoteConfig.getTemplate();

      const featureList = JSON.stringify({
        [data.featureName]: data.featureState,
      });

      if (!template.parameterGroups[`${country}_${poolId}`]) {
        template.parameterGroups[`${country}_${poolId}`] = {
          parameters: {
            [`${country}_${poolId}_features`]: {
              valueType: 'JSON',
              defaultValue: {value: featureList},
            },
          },
          description: `tenant of pool id ${poolId} from ${country}'s feature list`,
        };
      } else {
        template.parameterGroups[`${country}_${poolId}`].parameters[
          `${country}_${poolId}_features`
        ] = {
          valueType: 'JSON',
          defaultValue: {
            value: featureList,
          },
          description: `tenant of pool id ${poolId} from ${country}'s feature list`,
        };
      }

      const result = await remoteConfig.publishTemplate(template);
      ...
      // Handle result
    } catch (error: any) {
      ...
      // Handle errors
    }
  });
```